# Isn't Reverse Engineering That Dangerous?

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, reverse-engineering, exif

I spent a couple of hours reading over Reverse Engineering Specifically with relation to C/C++ and Exif file formats.

2 Questions which I couldn't find clear answers for:

1. Why Exif format at all? what's the reason to keep application's assembly exposed? Isn't there anyway to hide it so only the OS can extract the assembly code to run it?
2. If I can read assembly code of any program so why can't I do the following as example:

Open EXIF file for excel, find the function related to check for activation of the program and make it always return true?

Comment: _EXIF_? Do you mean EXE?

Comment: Question 2: Nothing except the difficulty of finding the function in an enormous amount of assembly code.

Comment: Question 2: that is why basically any commercial program has cracked versions where any licensing check is removed.

Comment: Question 1: you need some code / language the CPU understands and can execute, and if the CPU can understand it you can understand it and change it. There is absolutely nothing you can do about that.

Comment: You could write a crippled OS that doesn't allow other program to open executable files to read or write them, only to exec.  But you still need some file format for the OS's program loader to parse.  (And you need some way to install and back up your system, unless you have something like an Android or iOS phone where things are so locked down you can't do normal stuff.)  Any system where the hard drive can be removed will ultimately let you access the bytes of the files on it, so you can't stop users from using their hardware, only make things suck for users with only one system.

Comment: For starters because you repeatedly talk about exif which is nonesense in this context.

Comment: Re "Open [EXE] file for excel, find the function related to check for activation of the program and make it always return true". It is somewhat likely that after you make such a change the executable will not start because it fails a checksum test that ensures the integrity of the binary (which fail with a modified binary that produces a different checksum).

Comment: @njuffa ur answer contradicts what luk2303's answer about cracking...

Comment: @Robert I am speaking from experience. And there is no contradiction. A checksum mechanism will defeat lesser-skilled individuals. People with advanced skills may have knowledge how to work around particular checksum mechanisms. Also see point (a) in Brendan's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> Why Exif format at all? what's the reason to keep application's assembly exposed?

The "exe" file format (which is probably Microsoft's PE32+ file format) does not contain any assembly language. Instead if contains machine code (a bunch of numbers that the CPU executes) and data; with headers describing where different pieces of the program should be loaded into memory.

The machine code can normally be disassembled. This can be prevented in multiple ways (self modifying code, clever tricks like jumping into the middle of an instruction); but most tools (e.g. C compilers, linkers, etc) don't support self modifying code or clever tricks so they're mostly only used in extreme cases (hand written assembly designed to confuse debuggers, etc).

Another method that could prevent disassembly in theory is encryption; possibly with the OS decrypting pages/pieces of code when they're first executed and discarding the decrypted pages/pieces of code when they haven't been used for a small while. This isn't supported by any OS (that I'm aware of); likely because it'd have a high performance cost.

> If I can read assembly code of any program so why can't I do the following as example: Open EXIF file for excel, find the function related to check for activation of the program and make it always return true?

A disassembly of the original machine code can't just be "re-assembled" back into machine code. If you modify the machine code then you can alter the original program (e.g. disable an activation check). However, there are ways to prevent this, including:

a) Digital signatures. The basic idea is that the publisher of an executable creates a secure hash ("a big checksum") of their file then encrypts the result with a private key; and anyone else (the OS) can also create a secure hash of the file and compare it to the expected result from the publisher (from decrypting the publisher's result using the publisher's public key) to determine if file was modified after it was published (and then refuse to execute it if it was tampered with). This is used/supported by Windows, MacOS, UEFI secure boot, etc.

b) Not having an activation function that returns a "yes or no" result (where it's easy for a hacker to guess the "right" value to return), but having an activation function that returns something more complex (e.g. an encryption key that is needed to decrypt needed configuration or confidential data) where it's almost impossible for a hacker to guess the "right" value to return.

c) Shifting the activation check out of the executable and into something else (a dynamically linked/shared library, the OS, a remote server on the Internet, etc).